# Local hostname not working without the trailing dot

Tags: networking, router, dns, dd-wrt, dnsmasq

I noticed all my local hostnames have a trailing dot at the end when I use some LAN scan tool on my Android phone. And without it, I can't get a ping to work from my Windows desktop (it works fine from my Linux VMs):

```
C:\Users\dnll>ping router
Ping request could not find host router. Please check the name and try again.

C:\Users\dnll>ping router.

Pinging router [192.168.1.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

This is more obvious when trying to reach my router web UI as I need to enter `http://router./` since `http://router/` won't work. I'm using DD-WRT with dnsmasq enabled, not sure if that could be the issue. I'd prefer the hostnames to be reachable without the dot from my Windows PC.

[image: dnsmasq settings]

I tried disabling the local DNS without much success.

Here is `ipconfig /all` from my desktop:

```
C:\Users\dnll>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : desktop
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (5) I219-V
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 70-4D-7B-67-7C-FD
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.205(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : December 12, 2018 18:11:50
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : December 17, 2018 00:21:37
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

There is nothing really special about my Windows configuration that I know of. I'm not using a domain, at least not that I know of (and I tried a ping to `router.local` or `router.mydomain` without success, just to be sure).

What's wrong?

Comment: What Windows version are you using?

Comment: Tried on 3 different Windows desktops so far, all Windows 10.

Answer (score 6):

The dot at the end is required to force a DNS lookup. Without it, Windows may try
first other methods such as NETBIOS or the `hosts` file,
which it will not try if the dot is present.
When you put a dot, you are saying the host-name is fully qualified,
otherwise it will add your DNS suffix.
The final "dot" is always implied in DNS even if it's not specified.

From the DD-WRT forum article
[Can't resolve hostname but can resolve hostname. (with a . )](https://forum.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=50648):

> This is typical DNS behavior.
>
> The "trailing dot" signifies a fully qualified domain name (FQDN).
>   Without the dot, the name you are trying to ping is ambiguous (having
>   several possible meanings or interpretations).
>
> You can help prevent the use of trailing dot by specifying a LAN
>   domain of (for example) "local" in the router. Then release/renew DHCP
>   on the client.
>
> ```
> ping stan.local
>
> ping stan
> ```

So if your router's host-name would be `router.local.`, and your DNS resolver
would have a search path of `local`, when doing a lookup for `router`
the DNS client will automatically append the `.local.` and then
successfully resolve the address.

Comment: Except please don’t use `.local`, it’s reserved for Multicast DNS. Ideally, you’d use a domain you actually own.

Comment: I tried local, rebooted my router, did a `ipconfig /release` and `/renew` on my desktop and `ping router.local` still doesn't work (and the dot is still needed). So I changed it to my own domain name because I do happen to have one (which shouldn't be necessary to make my hostnames working, really) and that didn't change anything either.

Comment: As the above didn't help, I don't think that this is a DD-WRT problem but a problem with dnsmasq. This [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/800601/dnsmasq-address-of-host-with-no-tld-with-address) might help. But I can't help asking why do you need dnsmasq when not working with a large number of computers. For running on a local network, editing the hosts file is easier.

Comment: @harrymc I don't "need" dnsmasq per se, just thought it might help improve performances. I'm not dealing with a large number of computers per se but I do have a server with a ton of VMs so generally I have over 15 different IPs connected to the LAN.

Comment: I added a paragraph which might help in configuring router name and Windows domain in a way that works.

Comment: @harrymc I'm not sure exactly what I need to do. I did add a domain name to the DD-WRT configuration but it didn't change anything. Do I need to configure anything from my Windows desktop? People are upvoting your answer which I assume should be good but it just doesn't work for me currently and I'm trying to understand why. It seems like dnsmasq can't even be disabled easily in DD-WRT.

Comment: According to the documentation, to disable DNSMasq you need in Setup > Basic Setup, to uncheck `Use DNSMasq for DHCP` and `Use DNSMasq for DNS`, then click Apply before Save. If this doesn't solve the problem, please list your settings on the router and in Windows (ipconfig /all).

Comment: When you add a domain name to your router, does `ping router.<your-domain-name>` work?

Comment: Nope, it sadly doesn't @Binarus. I basically decided to just ignore the problem for now. I noticed it's a lot slower without the trailing dot in the rare instances where I got a Windows PC to work with a hostname without the trailing dot so I basically just use the dot all the time now, it's probably a nice habit.

Comment: OK, this is probably the best solution if you use Windows rarely. However, I would have been curious because I am using Windows PCs (besides Linux) all the time and have never got that problem.

Comment: @Binarus It works with the dot in Linux too (it works with and without it). In Windows it's very random honestly... I duplicated a VM and changed its hostname and noticed some of them would work without the dot and others needed it. There is definitely some sort of issue but heh. If it works 100% of the time in Linux, can I really blame DD-WRT config for it? It's weird, honestly.

Comment: I still can't get this to work. I can ping computer. and it finds the right ip from the hosts file of the dnsmasq server, but if I ping computer I get nothing. When I added the .lan domain I can now ping computer.lan but I'm hoping to get it set so I can just ping computer

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1429337/how-to-setup-dnsmasq-on-ubuntu-18-04-to-allow-windows-clients-to-find-hosts-with

Comment: I don't have a DNS suffix configured on Windows. So should `ping name` not work whenever `ping name.` works, given that `ping name` looks at more locations? So if those other locations (hosts file) don't contain the name, it should still find it eventually in the normal locations also looked up by `ping name.`. But to my surprise, `ping name` doesn't work while `ping name.` does.