# How to setup dnsmasq on Ubuntu 18.04 to allow windows clients to find hosts without trailing dot

Tags: windows, ubuntu, dnsmasq

I've got dnsmasq setup on Ubuntu 18.04. Its working fine and everything seems to be going swimmingly.

What I want is for all of the Windows hosts on my network that use the DNS server to be able to ping another host without a trailing .

For instance:

```
C:\Users\Alex>ping computer1.

Pinging computer1 [10.0.3.50] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.0.3.50: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127
Reply from 10.0.3.50: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=127
Reply from 10.0.3.50: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127
Reply from 10.0.3.50: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=127

Ping statistics for 10.0.3.50:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 0ms

C:\Users\Alex>ping computer1
Ping request could not find host computer1. Please check the name and try again.
```

I realize this is somewhat silly but we have a lot of mapped drives on a lot of computers and I really don't want to have to teach everyone and then have them do a remap of everything just to add the dot.

Some of the machines are on different VLANs, so I have setup dnsmasq with the hosts file that point to the right IP.

If I ping `computer.` it works.

If I ping `computer.lan` it works cause I setup the local domain to be .lan.

But if I ping `computer` I get nothing.

This is on Windows and Linux machines.

Here is the dnsmasq.conf

```
#/etc/dnsmasq.conf

domain-needed
bogus-priv

expand-hosts

local=/.lan/
domain=lan

listen-address=127.0.0.1
listen-address=10.0.10.2

server=127.0.0.1
server=8.8.4.4
server=8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Under Linux clients you may try to add `search .net` in the file `/etc/resolv.conf`...

Comment: It works in linux now, it's the windows clients I'm having issues with and that 95% of the clients on this network run.

Comment: Does [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/1385024/8672) apply here?

Comment: Could you just create a bash file called ping2 that would append the .? They would call it with "ping2 computer1"

Comment: @harrymc I did see that before posting and no it does not resolve my issue with Windows clients. I can still ping them adding the trailing . but not without. Also I added the dnsmasq.conf to verify I don't have something wrong there.

Comment: @raphael75 On linux clients, everything is working as expected without a bash script but the script idea just takes the problem and shifts it. Instead of remembering to add a trailing . they would have to remember to add a trailing 2 when pinging but most of the time they are just browsing to the machine for its shared files.

Comment: @ahackney Could you create an alias for the ping command and pass it to your own version that would append the .? You could keep a list of server names/IP's for the Windows computers (or have some method of detection) that would let your script know whether to append the period.

Comment: The idea there is to sneak the dot into the domain name so as to force Windows tools use DNS. Why doesn't it help?

Comment: @harrymc I supposed its not helping because its not searching the .lan domain for the computer. That answer does not specify to do anything beyond specifing a local domain which you can see, I have done. When I go from a windows device to ping computer it does not find it, even though it's in the dnsmasq hosts file. Do I need to add the entry in the hosts file as computer.lan then try again? It's my understanding that when I added the local domain, it will look for a computer.local and if it doesnt find it, then look for computer from the hosts file and add the lan automatically, it's not.

Comment: I can still ping computer. and computer.lan but computer can not be found. However if I do a nslookup from the windows device for computer, it finds it. When I do one for computer. or computer.lan it finds them as well. I just can't figure out why I cant ping computer

Comment: The idea is to call the domain `lan.` so when appended this will become `computer.lan.` (with ending dot) and DNS will then be used. I don't know if you can make this work, but this idea is nicely sneaky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the dot at the end of the domain:

```
domain=lan.
```

Also make sure that the hostname of your DNS server is fully qualified with the dot at the end.

```
hostname.lan.
```

NOTE: The `local` directive only works if the DNS server is also the DHCP server. If it isn't then you would have to populate the hosts file with entries for local hostnames.

Comment: I litterally have all of these in my conf thats posted in the question. What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, you're missing the dot at the end of the domain.

Comment: This is what I have been advising the poster in the comments to do since 5 days ago.

Comment: Why didn't you post the answer?

Comment: @HackSlash This has not solved my issue. I'm still at a loss here. if I have a line in /etc/hosts with 10.0.0.1 comptest I can ping comptest. from the windows client but not comptest

Comment: If all else fails you can spin up a WINS server on this Ubuntu box. Windows will still query for NetBIOS name if DNS fails. I know this is a shitty workaround but it's one that Windows has been employing on small networks since the dawn of time. https://www.oreilly.com/openbook/samba/book/ch07_03.html