# How to make Rasperry Pi hostname visible on Mac without ".local"

Tags: mac, afp, netatalk

Using [Netatalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netatalk), I am able to mount my Raspberry Pi on my Mac by typing `open afp://mypi.local` in Terminal. I would like to be able to access the Pi without always having to type in ".local".

Trying `open afp://mypi` results in an error message:

```
There was a problem connecting to the server "mypi".
```

Similarly, `ping mypi.local` works but `ping mypi` results in an error:

```
ping: cannot resolve mypi: Unknown host.
```

Comment: Try "mypi." with a trailing dot; see [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1385021/local-hostname-not-working-without-the-trailing-dot)

Comment: Adding a trailing dot did not work..

Comment: Have you tried just putting `mypi` in your `hosts` file?

Comment: `.local` means name resolution is currently working with mDNS. Unless you set up name resolution (`hosts` file, DNS server, whatever) to resolve `mypi` to the desired IP address, this won’t work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My raspberry pi hosts file `/etc/hosts` contains
`127.0.1.1       mypi` and the file /etc/hostname contains `mypi` so not sure what else to do.

Comment: `/etc/hosts` is local to each computer, so adding "mypi" to `/etc/hosts` on the Pi only has any effect *on the Pi*, not on the Mac. You'd need to add it to the `/etc/hosts` file on the Mac to do what you want.